# Using min leaf size above 1 in random forest/treebagging

Tags: random-forest, cart

Are there any advantages in using a min-leaf-size above 1 in classification with bagged trees(/random forests)? I would imagine that it could make the classification more robust as some area in the fature-space where it is improbable with cases of one class, any case of that class will be surrounded by the many more of the probable cases in the other class. On the other hand, as the data is split into different partitions this could be taken care of implicitly anyways..?